# Filling indexedDb with data, so you don't need to make a second request using Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

`useState()` in a Nuxt3 has a power of sending data to client after fetching it on server side (except rendered HTML file, it sends JSON file with data saved using `useState()`).

Like I mentioned in the title, I want to fill indexedDB on client side with data, so I don't need to fetch data again. I `enableIndexedDbPersistence(getFirestore())` in a plugin on client side.

Example of component where I want to save existing data to indexedDB:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Data</h1>
        {{ data }}
    </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { getDocs, collection, getFirestore } from '@firebase/firestore/lite'

const data = useState('test2')

// data.value === unknown on server side, but on client it has data
if(!data.value) {
    const result = await getDocs(collection(getFirestore(), 'test2'))
    if(!result.empty) data.value = result.docs.map(docSnap => { return { ...docSnap.data(), id: docSnap.id } })
} else {
    // Fill indexedDB maintained by JS Firebase client SDK
    // `enableIndexedDbPersistence(getFirestore())`
    // with data so SDK wont need to fetch data again
    // when i use `onSnapshot()` with same query
}
</script>
```

**For people not know how Nuxt3 works:**

Code in `<script setup>` tag run server side and template is rendered. `useState()` is a state management with a powerful feature. It sends a JSON file with data to a client so when the component is opened on the client it already has fetched `data` done one server side. That why `if(!data.value)` statement to prevent from double fetch.

Comment: Or should I just use PWA and lave that first initial connection with my web app where Nuxt3 make twice request?

Comment: What do you mean by "indexedDB"? Do you mean the cache created/maintained by the JS SDK in local?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Firestore `enableIndexedDbPersistence(getFirestore())` is saving there data, I think so.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I forget to write yeah cached/maintained by JS SDK in local. I want to fill it with data fetched on server side, so it thinks it did a request before and have fresh data when i will use `onSnapshot()` with same query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I store and persist data using Firebase client SDK in a browser using `enableIndexedDbPersistence(getFirestore())`, Nuxt3 still will make requests to a server every time a user open a new tab to my web app. It's happening because files I'm getting from the server have headers with `Cache-Control: max-age=0`.

Best way will be to just make PWA (Progressive Web Application) where I can manipulate files headers and change `Cache-Control: max-age=X`, so the app will work as SPA (Single Page Application) every time user visit again my web app, and `enableIndexedDbPersistence(getFirestore())` from Firebase SDK will do the work.

And there is no point to "Prevent second query by Firebase on client side" if PWA will prevent Nuxt3 from SSR every time user opens tab. All I can benefit from it is to save one query when user visit my web page first time in a brawser.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO I don't think it is a good idea to try "manipulating" data stored and managed by the JS SDK in the local persistent storage. The cache management is a quite complex process and is not a matter of just pushing data to the browser local storage.

If I correctly understand your requirement, it is already covered by the local cache mechanism: If a document is in the local cache, as long as the document in the database is not changed any subsequent read is done from the cache. If a document in the database is changed, it is fetched from the Firestore back-end and you are charged with a document read.

Comment: Yeah, correct `useState()` function is a state management tool. It works on a server and a client. It has a powerful future where if it has data on server it sends it to a client together with rendered HTML file. So when browser open, app data already exists in a `const data`. And I just want to be sure that data is fresh using `onSnapshot()` and not make extra request for same data on client side.

Comment: And main problem is without PWA, every user might open an application/tab in browser few times in a day, and it will make double fetch on server and client if I won't use future of `useState()` or PWA.

Comment: Nah, I realize that even if I have this data persisted on storage by Firebase SDK browser still make request and fetch will happen on server without PWA.

Comment: "every user might open an application/tab in browser few times in a day, and it will make double fetch on server" => Yes, the browser storage used by the persistence mechanism is attached to the browser and the device. Note that if the data you want to cache is infrequently changed (e.g. reference data, e.g. a list of products) you could take advantage of [Cloud Firestore bundles](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/serve-bundles) (Watch also this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iQOTjUko9WM)).

Comment: I answered a question, do you think it answers well my question?